# Cannot Publish SQL Server Database Project because of .NET compatibility issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I am in a situation where I cannot find a workaround.

I am trying to develop an SQL CLR project on Visual Studio 2015 where you can do POST and GET HTTP requests from SQL server. I was able to implement what I needed to do on a console application, then I decided to carry that to SQL Server Database Project. Database in question has compatibility level of 2008 which forces me to change the target framework of the project to .NET 2.0, otherwise it doesn't publish. But references I use like Npgsql and Newtonsoft JSON require project to be .Net 4.6.1 or they don't work.

I tried to create the assembly manually. But database is in a server like 192.168.x.x and I didn't know where to put dll file for create assembly script to work.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

**Update:** So following Solomon's advices I was able to find .NET 2.0 compatible versions of Npgsql and Newtonsoft.json. I was able to add Newtonsoft.json as assembly to database, but Npgsql doesn't work. It requires Mono.Security.dll to be in same folder as Npgsql if it isn't, and when you add it to folder, Mono.Security.dll cannot pass verification probably because it is a mixed assembly. This is the error message it gives;

> CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'Npgsql' failed because assembly
> 'Mono.Security' failed verification. Check if the referenced
> assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe)
> to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will
> follow this message

I will try to find a workaround on this workaround by using ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server 2008 you can do up to .NET Framework version 3.5, but not beyond that. Starting with SQL Server 2012 you can use the 4.x versions of the .NET Framework. There is no way around this. If you need to use 3rd party assemblies, you need to either get precompiled versions for .NET Framework versions 2.0 - 3.5, or get a version of the source code that will allow you to compile for one of those versions.

As far as deployment of assemblies goes, you should never deploy from a DLL as that is an external dependency of the deployment script that can get lost, or have issues with file system permissions based on who is executing the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement, etc. Visual Studio / SSDT *should* be generating a proper `CREATE ASSEMBLY ... FROM 0x....` statement that uses a `VARBINARY` literal / (hex bytes as it is called in the documentation), but if not, then you can always convert the DLL into the `0x...` binary string using a simple, open-source command-line utility I wrote: [BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/sqlquantumleap/binaryformatter/releases/latest).

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice. I've been looking for older versions that support .net 2.0 and found them in fact. but this time I am getting "npgsql was not found in the SQL catalog." error while publishing. is there any help you can provide on this one please?

Comment: @HakanAliYasdi Glad you were able to find a 2.0 version of Json.NET. As for NpgSQL, that would be the same thing: find a version of it that works with CLR 2.0 (so Framework versions 2.0 - 3.5) and upload that before the assembly that is requiring it.

Comment: @SolomonRotzky I'll try that and give feedback as soon as I can. thank you for the answers.